# How to return a value of a register from ARM assembly to a C function?

Tags: c, function, assembly, arm, return

for example

```
extern int addfunction(int,int);
main() {
  int a = 5, b = 6, z;
  z = addfunction(a, b);
  printf("%d", c);
}
```

`addfunction()`'s defintion in another .s file like

```
.global addfunction
addfunction:
    @ value a will be in R0 & R1 respectively
    add r2, r0, r1    @ r2=r0+r1
```

Now how to return value stored `r2` so that variable `z` in the C program will get correct the value? I am able to do with pointer from C and update the address in asm. I don't want this way. Help!

Comment: afaik return value is in r0, so using `add r0,r0,r1` instead will do the job ( and you need to return to the caller, of course )

Comment: @Tommylee2k.. that is what mentioned in reference too. i tried , but not working.

Comment: its working.. my original program had logical error. Anyway this question will help for others too

Comment: You will need to consult the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_.28A32.29).

Answer (score 4):

Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM)

> The standard 32-bit ARM calling convention allocates the 16 ARM registers as:
>
> > r0 to r3: used to hold argument values passed to a subroutine, and also hold results returned from a subroutine.

So set r0 to the return value

```
.global addfunction
addfunction:
    @ value a will be in R0 & R1 respectively
    add r0, r0, r1    @ r0=r0+r1
```

Comment: Also don't forget `bx lr` to actually return, using the return address passed by the caller.

Comment: I think a better alternative is `mov pc, lr`